# Can I connect bluetooth device automatically with the device which already paired without showing choose dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

I am developing a solution for connection between OBD2(Vehicle ECU scanner) with the mobile app. 
I want that when ever that OBD device is found and it is already paired then the application automatically connect with the device and create a socket for transmission of data . without showing the dialog box to choose a paired device.

Comment: if you know the MAC address of your bluetooth device (which you are going to connect) you can connect it programmatically .

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to any paired Bluetooth device, to do so, you have to know device's address and UUID. Embedded devices may have some defined uuid (for example, hc05 adapter), you can get that uuid from documentation. 
The tricky part here is that you have to monitor failure and loss of connection so you can retry again. I'm implementing that feature in my home project, fell free to see code: https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It means when ever i paired with device I have to save UUID e.g in preferences or Database for next time...
Are you sure then it will not ask again for choose device in UI ?

Comment: Unless if you tell Android to pick device manually. Actually, you can scan scan for devices without UI. (see BtScanPort in project). When you connect two phones, UUID is app - specific key, describing connection between applications - you generate it by yourself. For embedded devices it usually pre- defined.

Comment: Yep I am working with embedded device (OBD2 Vehicle ECU Scanner).

Comment: @MuhammadJamal can you please help me , How we will generate UUID